# a href refers to site itself + link instead of the link itself

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, hyperlink, href

In Codeigniter, I have a database containing a link of a site.
Each item(event) has a link to the event page.

```
<a href="<?php echo $event->LinkSite; ?>">Site</a>
```

But instead of going to the desired site, it just adds the link to the existing url like this: http://web.site.local/index.php/evenementen/www.referedsite.com
when checking the html code it shows the following:

```
<a href="www.referedsite.com">Site</a>
```

Does anyone know how to make it go to www.referedsite.com instead of making it add this to the existing link?

Comment: your link comes from database ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put HTTP://

```
<a href="http://www.referedsite.com">Site</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In codeignitor you can use

```
echo anchor('', 'Site');
// Prints: <a href="http://example.com">Site</a>
```

Read [CI Anchor](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $event->LinkSite; ?>">Site</a>
```